# Place text behind background image

Tags: html, css, layout, position

Right now I am having trouble placing a paragraph behind a background image. I have tried using z-index and position relative, but have not found any success. How could I do this?

```css
.pageone {
  background-image: url(headerhalf.png);
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

#aboutme {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 5vw;
  margin-top: 6vh;
    color: #81af66;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 3px rgba(129, 131, 131, 0.25);
}

.pagecontainer {
  width: 50vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;

}

#aboutcopy {
  font-size: 1.25vw;
  margin: 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="pageone">
  <div class="pagecontainer">
    <div class="aboutreal">
      <p id="aboutme">About Me</p>
      <p id="aboutcopy">I run a YouTube channel on which I benchmark the performance of computer hardware. I've been uploading content to YouTube for upwards of one year, and have amassed over 80 thousand views in that time period. While I'm not managing my channel I design graphics for others and myself. I design product advertisements, avatars and banners for YouTube, websites, logos, and more. I am comfortable with a wide variety of softwares such as: Adobe Photoshop, Adobe After Effects, Adobe Premiere Pro and, Unreal Engine 4. I am also learning HTML and CSS.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is a link to the site: [site](https://1080benchmarks.github.io/testportfolio.html)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try the CSS `:after` selector:

```
.pageone {
  background-image: url(headerhalf.png);
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position:relative;   
}

.pageone:after {
  content:"Your text here";
  position: absolute;
  top:20px;
  right:20px;
}
```

Comment: What is CSS persuade ?

Comment: CSS pseudo like you can add relative element to your html element as the code above :after, you can read more about CSS pseudo :https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_elements.asp

Comment: Are you sure it's called that ? The word "persuade" isn't mentioned in that page. Do you mean "pseudo-elements" ?

Comment: yes sorry for that: what I mean that you can add your text within the content property and give it z-index to be behind the image

Comment: No problem :) :)

Comment: also you need to add overflow-x: hidden; to your body to fix the scroll issue :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154047/discussion-between-medhat-and-taurus).

Comment: Sorry if my question was unclear. I'm trying to hide the about copy behind the right triangle of the image. So when you scroll down it comes from behind it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your trying put an element behind its *parent* element, which is not possible in the regular page flow. One option is create another  `<div>` at the same level of the about element and put the image there:

```css
.pageone {
  /* moved to #headerhalf */
  /*background-image: url(headerhalf.png);
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;*/
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative; /*needed because of absolute positioning of #headerhalf */
}

#headerhalf {
  /*background-image: url(headerhalf.png);*/
  /* simulating semi-transparent PNG for the sample snippet*/
  opacity: 0.9;
  background-color: ForestGreen;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute; /*removed element from normal flow to make it full size*/
  z-index: 1;
}

.pagecontainer {
  width: 50vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

#aboutme {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 5vw;
  margin-top: 6vh;
    color: #81af66;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 3px rgba(129, 131, 131, 0.25);
}

#aboutcopy {
  font-size: 1.25vw;
  margin: 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="pageone">
  <div class="pagecontainer">
    <div id="headerhalf"></div>
    <div class="aboutreal">
      <p id="aboutme">About Me</p>
      <p id="aboutcopy">I run a YouTube channel on which I benchmark the performance of computer hardware. I've been uploading content to YouTube for upwards of one year, and have amassed over 80 thousand views in that time period. While I'm not managing my channel I design graphics for others and myself. I design product advertisements, avatars and banners for YouTube, websites, logos, and more. I am comfortable with a wide variety of softwares such as: Adobe Photoshop, Adobe After Effects, Adobe Premiere Pro and, Unreal Engine 4. I am also learning HTML and CSS.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I think that it could be possible achieve this without using absolute positioning, but this method is quite straightforward.